# How to fix "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" in NodeJS/Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm sending a network POST request from a javascript function to a node.js server. I get this error response on the front-end:

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://server.herokuapp.com/connect/link' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8888' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

javascript that uses `fetch()` to make a call looks like this:

```
function submitId() {
  $("#progress-label").text("Working...")
  const request = {
    method: "POST",
    body: {
      docId: $('#id').val(),
      stripeId: USER_ID
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }
  fetch(SERVER_URL + "/link", request).then(res => {
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = res.msg
  }).catch(err => {
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = res.msg
  })
 }
```

Node.js server:

```
var express = require('express'),
    stripeConnect = require('./routes/connect'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
});

app.use('/connect', connect);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

routes/connect.js looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: process.env.projectId,
        clientEmail: process.env.clientEmail,
        privateKey: process.env.privateKey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
        clientId: process.env.clientId
    }),
    databaseURL: process.env.databaseURL
});
const STRIPE_SK = 'sk_test_KEY';
const stripe = require('stripe')(STRIPE_SK);

// @route POST /stripeConnect/link
// @desc save stripe user account id to their firebase profile
// @access public
router.post('/link', (req, res) => {
    console.log('\nSTRIPE-LINK-REQUEST-BODY => ');
    console.log(req.body);

    return admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(req.body.docId)
        .update({ stripeId: req.body.stripeId })
        .then((success) => res.json({ msg: 'Stripe account ID added to profile.' }))
        .catch((err) => res.json({ msg }));
});

module.exports = router;
```

the error I receive server-side is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>   2020-03-13T00:10:29.151249+00:00 app[web.1]:     at JSON.parse
>   () 2020-03-13T00:10:29.151251+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   parse (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
>   2020-03-13T00:10:29.151251+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   /app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
>   2020-03-13T00:10:29.151251+00:00 app[web.1]:     at invokeCallback
>   (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
>   2020-03-13T00:10:29.151251+00:00 app[web.1]:     at done
>   (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
>   2020-03-13T00:10:29.151252+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   IncomingMessage.onEnd (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
>   2020-03-13T00:10:29.151253+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
>   2020-03-13T00:10:29.151253+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT
>   (_stream_readable.js:1204:12) 2020-03-13T00:10:29.151253+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections
>   (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

How can I fix this to successfully submit the post request?

Comment: I don't think you should both `.use(cors())` and manually set the headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server-side error does not indicate a CORS error.  That indicates a JSON parsing error.

It appears to me that you are not correctly sending JSON content so the recipient is getting a JSON parsing error.  With `fetch()`,  you have to manually turn your data into JSON before sending.  Change this:

```
body: {
  docId: $('#id').val(),
  stripeId: USER_ID
},
```

to this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  docId: $('#id').val(),
  stripeId: USER_ID
}),
```

See [JSON sending example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options).

Comment: Why we need to `stringify` ? Read somewhere that we only needed when working with nested object, but It appears to be mandatory

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro - Unlike other http libraries such as `got()` and `axios()`, `fetch()` will not automatically call `JSON.stringify()` if you just pass it a plain object for the body.  You can see from the [MDN doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#body) that it takes a lot of different types of data in the `body` property, but none of them are a plain object.  So, if you want to send an object, you must stringify it yourself.  Likewise, `fetch()` doens't parse the response for you automatically either as you have to call the appropriate type of parser.